# "Just happast an asshole" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Garraty looked at his watch, but it was stopped at 10:16. He had forgotten to wind it. " Anybody got the time?" he asked.

> "Lemme see. " Pearson squinted at his watch. "***Just happast an asshole***, Garraty."

> Everyone laughed. "Come on, " he said. "My watch stopped."

> Pearson looked again. "It's two after two."

> The Long Walk

According to the context, it's supposed to be a joke. But I really don't get it. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: It's not really a "joke" - just Pearson injecting a note of scatology into the conversation. If you insist on trying to "deconstruct" it any further, you might say *half-past **an asshole*** (rather than the expected *half-past twelve* or similar) is Pearson "obliquely" calling Garraty an asshole (as in he's replying ***after / past** the time that* Garraty asked for a timecheck).

Comment: It might not be a joke per say, but certainly it is an attempt at humor—on Gerrity's part and/or the author's.